# Use Docker to invoke .NET Core from Java

Tags: java, docker, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have made a small .NET Core REST API which I would like to be able to easily put on a Linux server running a Java app on Tomcat. Can one use Docker to ease the deployment of the .NET tool, and if so, how is it done? I was told by someone that Docker would (more or less) allow me to bundle the API as a single app/file without having to bother too much about deployment policies at the place I am working (which by default only allows for Java apps to Bd deployed).

Comment: Follow this link [Tutorial: Containerize a .NET Core app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/docker/build-container)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a docker image like e.g. [microsoft/dotnet](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-core) to run your app in a docker container. Please read the documentation on the linked page on how to run your app inside the container.

If you then map an exposed port (443, 80, 8080... depends on you app) using the -p option on container startup you can then access the REST endpoints from any software you like because it is basically behaving like an other REST server running on that host. Since you want to run tomcat in parallel you should avoid to map the port from the container to 8080 on you host, thought! Other than that this setup is totally independent from the application server running on the host itself.